# Remove a li item from its class

Tags: jquery

I have a table that I'm trying to remove a list item, when an icon is clicked.

[image]

So when I click the trash icon, and the trash icon *only*, I want to remove that list item, and move the others "up".

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="list">TO-DO LIST<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></div></div>
    <ul class="toDoList" style="list-style: none;">
        <li id="addToDo"><input type='text' id="addToDoText" placeholder="Add New ToDo"></input></li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Buy Robes</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Fight Malfoy</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Buy New Wand</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Kill Voldemort</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Feed Hedwig</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Send Owl to Sirius</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Do Dishes</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Wash Robes</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Buy Hagrid's Birthday Gift</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my jQuery, which includes the code for coloring the table alternate colors, which I want to keep when I remove an item.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  color_table();
});

function color_table(){
    $('.toDoList li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('alternate');
};

$('li .fa-trash').on("click", function(){
    var index = $(this).index(); // ...doesn't do anything. b/c no index of the class?
    var text = $('li').text(); // gets LI text correctly of current item
    console.log(index+" // "+text);
    $(this).remove(); // This should remove the LI entry, not just the icon class .fa-trash. If I use $('li').remove(), it removes the entire li list! Not just the current one.
    color_table();
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`closest()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp) method to get ancestor `li`.

```
$(this).closest('li').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks! That successfully removes the item. I have made an edit, as I have my table rows alternating colors.  How can I keep that coloring? When I remove an item, it'll then go grey-white-white or white-grey-grey.

Comment: You can use css for that instead of `JS`. https://jsfiddle.net/10omLxdo/ @BruceWayne

Answer (score 1):

You should target the parent `li` instead, you could use :

```
$(this).parents('li').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for this too.  Is this just another way to @Azim's answer, or are there any big differences or pitfalls in either that I should be aware of?